# cvs: update fails "no head revision"

Tags: cvs

I have an issue regarding cvs, I'm not able to update particular folder, other folders though are updated. When trying to update the whole folder i'm getting following message:

cvs update: /bla/.../blabla.cpp,v: no head revision

and for any particular file update is claimed to be finished successfully though the file is not updated.
 I've tried removing that folder and updating in order to get an up to date copy, but then i'm getting the old version again.

Can I somehow cope with it avoiding making a new check out?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem once, when I was working in my own branch and couldn't re-add and re-commit some files I accidentally messed up, and I fixed this problem by:

(*But my method has 2 prerequisites: These files have "lock: strict" in the output of cvs log, and You have separate copy of these files.*)

1. unlock these certain files by "cvs admin -U filename".
2. checkout out from another older tag into another local folder.
3. cd to this new local checkout.
4. cvs remove -f filename(*-f for forcing filename to be deleted from disk*).
5. manually move the good copies over to this new local checkout.
6. cvs add filename.
7. cvs commit filename.
8. Then I switched back to my own branch where I had same problems, I was able to re-add and re-commit these files without problem.

I'm not CVS guru, just trying to help here, so please feel free to point out redundant or wrong cvs steps here.